# ConfigParser python 2.7. Delimiter is getting changed to '=' after config write

Tags: python, python-2.7, configparser

I have a file looks like below

```
[SectionOne]
Status: Single
Name: Derek
Value: Yes
Age: 30
Single: True
```

After i read and modify a field, the delimiter is getting changed to '=' instead of ':' as below

```
[SectionOne]
Status = Married
Name = Derek
Value = Yes
Age = 30
Single = True
```

I am using python 2.7 and i cannot migrate to a new version of python now.

the code is below

```
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("Bacpypes.ini")
cfgfile = open("Bacpypes.ini")
Config.set('SectionOne', 'Status', 'Married')
Config.write(cfgfile
cfgfile.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `ConfigParser` in Python 3 allows defining the "delimiters". The version in Python 2 does not.

Comment: ...but you could subclass `ConfigParser`, overwrite `write` and replace the `=` in [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/815fa49d1030b52a6e5fae924f92907240d90155/Lib/ConfigParser.py#L412) with a `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to subclass the `ConfigParser` to modify its behaviour so it writes a `:` instead of `=`:

```
class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):

    def write(self, fp):
        """Write an .ini-format representation of the configuration state."""
        if self._defaults:
            fp.write("[%s]\n" % DEFAULTSECT)
            for (key, value) in self._defaults.items():
                fp.write("%s = %s\n" % (key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
            fp.write("\n")
        for section in self._sections:
            fp.write("[%s]\n" % section)
            for (key, value) in self._sections[section].items():
                if key == "__name__":
                    continue
                if (value is not None) or (self._optcre == self.OPTCRE):
                    key = ": ".join((key, str(value).replace('\n', '\n\t')))
                fp.write("%s\n" % (key))
            fp.write("\n")
```

Then use `MyConfigParser`:

```
config = MyConfigParser()
config.read("Bacpypes.ini")
...
```

In addition to that there are two errors in your code:

- You did not open the file for writing.
- You have unbalanced parentheses.

Both should prevent the code from running.